# Program that makes appointments for a day in a specific hour (Without using arrays) C++

Tags: c++, list, date, appointment

I'm making a program so a therapist can make appointments for its patients. **The catch is that I can't use arrays, and preferably only use list type structures.** I was initially thinking about doing it with a list where itself it represents the month, and each node represents a day.
The structure in each node will look as:

```
Struct Hour{
    int hour;
    patientID;

{

Struct Day{
    int day;
    Struct Hour1; (Comment : From 7:00 to 8:00)
    Struct Hour2; (Comment : From 8:00 to 9:00)
    Struct Hour3; (Comment : From 9:00 to 10:00)
{
```

I am trying to do it this way since the date doesn't have to be exact. And there are 3 struct type Hour because the therapist only works 3 hours of the day, and the sesion only goes for 1 hour.
I'm making this question to know if someone else has a better or easier way or idea to implement this "calendar of appointments" kind of thing

Comment: Making a different struct for different hour seems a bit redundant. How about use same structure and have start_time and end_time as constants?

Comment: Additionally, although I can figure out what code you are trying to make, but It does not look like valid C++. If you modify it, it would be a lot clearer question.

Comment: why exaclty you cannot use arrays/std::vector??

Comment: Because it's an assignment and we are working with lists at the moment